# How can I change the text of a label when a button is checked?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am willing to change the text displayed by my heading only if a radio button is checked.I am using `input type="radio"` so I can style it using CSS. This is what my code looks like:

```html
<h1>What is your favourite class?</h1>

<div>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1" class="radio" />
  <label for="radio1" style="color:black;font-family:impact;text-align:center;" id='1'>Maths</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
           $('h1').text('Enter you new text');
        });
    });

</script>
```

`.change` detects the change in state of radio button.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mayank_shubham/gtd12gna/1/)

Comment: It works perfectly on the demo but when I copy the JS code it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @VladJ have you included the jquery.min.js file in your code.

Comment: I am using the script tag in my code. Do I still need to include that file?

Comment: what I meant is a link such as this  in your script tag https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js

Comment: Oh, thank you! I am still a noob at JS so I tend to make some mistakes. Your help is appreciated!

Comment: Its okk, I too was, a few days ago.Happy to help :)

Comment: Can you edit the code above including the jquery.min.js stuff please?

Comment: Its always better to create a seperate .js file  for your javascript and include that in your script tag. and yes that is correct. One more thing write this jquery script inside `$document.ready()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Add an ID to your Label and use Javascript to change the innerHTML of this label:

```
getElementById("label").innerHTML = "new Text here"
```

Comment: The label's id is id='1';

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is:

```js
// on document ready
$(function () {
  // when the radio changes
  $(':radio.radio').on('change', function(e) {
    // set text of h1 element
    $('h1').text('mmmmm');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>


<h1>What is your favourite class?</h1>

<div>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1" class="radio"/>
    <label for="radio1" style="color:black;font-family:impact;text-align:center;" id='1'>Maths</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `.change` to detect when someone clicks the radio button.

```
$('input[type=radio][name=radio]').change(function() {
  $(".header").text("New text");
});
```

Comment: Can you please replace the link with the relevant code or content summary? Each post needs to be self contained without leaving the site or needing to go to another post to understand the answer. see [help/answering](http://stackoverflow.com/help/answering)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `onchange` attribute for the checkbox and call the change function, which will change the text of the heading.

You only need JavaScript, no jQuery for this solution.

If you do not want to use the HTML `onchange` attribute, you can use an `eventListener` in your JavaScript.

```js
function change() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].textContent="Changed";
}
```

```html
<h1>What is your favourite class?</h1>

<div>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1" class="radio" onchange="change()"/>
  <label for="radio1" style="color:black;font-family:impact;text-align:center;" id='1'>Maths</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First check if the radio button is selected. If it is, change the innerHTML property of the label element.

```
if (document.getElementById('radio1').checked) document.getElementById('1').innerHTML = "Text to insert";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you only need a bit of js.

document.getElementById("radio").innerHTML = "Change text to this";

OR

Maybe you can try an if statement,

var radio;

if //radio button is clicked (.onclick = true) //sorry i dont know the proper code for this action/statement...not sure if this is possible. just working thru a thought process {

```
document.getElementById("radio").innerHTML = "Change text to this";
```

}

```html
<h1>What is your favourite class?</h1>

<div>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1" class="radio" />
  <label for="radio1" style="color:black;font-family:impact;text-align:center;" id='1'>Maths</label>
</div>
```